# Combo box changed, clear proceeding combo boxes

Tags: c#

I want to clear the combo boxes after a combo box has been changed.

For example, if I have combo boxes 1, 2 and 3 and if 2 has been changed then clear the contents of 3.

I am a little stuck on the logic of this. Should I be creating a recursive method to do such a thing? Or perhaps just use the "selectedindexchanged" events? Any thoughts on this would be of great help.

Comment: There's no need for a recursive method. The change events will suffice

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi winforms

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi I have 4 on the form.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure if you are using an MVVM pattern, or a web or desktop (winforms or wpf) application, so i am going to refrain from being technology specific.

One approach could be to implement the textchanged event of every textbox and handle the logic associated with each textbox. eg: 
texbox.textchange event has fired -> therefore cleartext(textbox2).

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe comboboxes to same event

```
bool _ignore;

private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // ignore event if programmatic change
    if(_ignore)
        return;

    _ignore = true;
    // instead of push/pop can be 3 if
    var index = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex; // push
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox2.SelectedIndex = comboBox3.SelectedIndex = -1;
    (sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex = index; // pop
    _ignore = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    int maxNo = 4; //you can change this no and logic works till 9 comboboxes
    void clearPreceding(ComboBox cmbBox)
    {
        int cmbBoxNo = Convert.ToInt32(cmbBox.Name.Substring(cmbBox.Name.Length - 1));
        for (int i = cmbBoxNo; i <= maxNo; i++)
        {
            ((ComboBox)this.Controls.Find("comboBox" + i, true)[0]).Text = "";
        }
    }
```

You can Subscribe to One EventHandler for all Combobox's `SelectedIndexChanges` Event as below:

```
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += AllCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        comboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += AllCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        comboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged += AllCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        comboBox4.SelectedIndexChanged += AllCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

and the EventHandler is:

```
   private void AllCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clearPreceding((ComboBox)sender);
    }
```

**Complete Code:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int maxNo = 4;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged+=AllCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        comboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += AllCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        comboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged += AllCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        comboBox4.SelectedIndexChanged += AllCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }
    private void AllCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clearPreceding((ComboBox)sender);
    }

    void clearPreceding(ComboBox cmbBox)
    {
        int cmbBoxNo = Convert.ToInt32(cmbBox.Name.Substring(cmbBox.Name.Length - 1));
        for (int i = cmbBoxNo; i <= maxNo; i++)
        {
            ((ComboBox)this.Controls.Find("comboBox" + i, true)[0]).Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```